# Not able to assign privileges to user in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, privileges

I am trying to create a new user and assign privileges to it, but it doesn't work. Below is the error.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '****';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH 
GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES)
```

Thanks

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db_name.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH 
GRANT OPTION;

Comment: His `*.*` is correct if he wants to create global privileges @KKK "To set a global privilege, use `*.*` for priv_level." source https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/

Comment: `IDENTIFIED BY 'dcmuc100';` if the MariaDB server is online i assume you are going to change the password again? Don't give hackers the chance to use social engineering and google search to possibly find and "hack" your server

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn't get your previous comment. Is there is any problem with the command which I ran?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Not this, comment before that :)

Comment: Basically i mean i don't see anny error within `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH 
GRANT OPTION`... it might help if you use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or disconnected and reconnect again as root did you try that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland still same after re-connection too. FLUSH PRIVILEGES gives  0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: I have a feeling you might need to restart MariaDB then completely.. Or if that doesn't work reinstall because it looks like it's corrupted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171910/discussion-between-nvnvashisth-and-raymond-nijland).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked by below command.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO '[user]'@'[hostname]' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```